# Group query in mongoDB using array items to calculate sum

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Each document in my collection has a property that is an array and that array has objects with properties such as total, index, etc. I want to group the documents by the sum of the total property of the second array element, like the query below. How can I make it happen?

I want to make this query work :

```
db.nwt_envio_contacto.aggregate({  
   $project:{  
      "visualizacoes":true,
      "envio_id":true
   }   ‌​
},
{  
   $match:{  
      "envio_id":ObjectId("54c5ed8101ec09c26c7b23c6"),
      "visualizacoes":{  
         $elem‌​Match:{  
            "index":1
         }
      }
   }
},
{  
   $group:{  
      _id:null,
      total:{  
         $sum:"visualizacoes.$.total"
      }
   }
})
```

Assume that I have a collection with this document :

```
{
   "_id":ObjectId("54c5ed8101ec09c26c7b23c8"),
   "envio_id":ObjectId("54c5ed8101ec09c26c7b23c6"),
   "visualizacoes":[
      {
         "primeira":"2015-01-26 09:34:58",
         "ultima":"2015-01-26 14:17:18",
         "index":2,
         "total":4
      },
      {
         "primeira":"2015-01-26 09:35:13",
         "ultima":"2015-01-26 09:35:43",
         "index":2,
         "total":3
      }
   ]
}
```

Basically I want to sum the total attribute of all visualizacoes objects that have the index equal to 1.

Comment: Can you clarify that a little more? Post a sample document and clearly explain the information you need to retrieve.

Comment: Assume that I have a collection with this document :
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54c5ed8101ec09c26c7b23c8"),
    "envio_id" : ObjectId("54c5ed8101ec09c26c7b23c6"),
    "visualizacoes" : [ 
        {
            "primeira" : "2015-01-26 09:34:58",
            "ultima" : "2015-01-26 14:17:18","index" : 2,
            "total" : 4
        }, 
        {
            "primeira" : "2015-01-26 09:35:13",
            "ultima" : "2015-01-26 09:35:43",
            "index" : 2,
            "total" : 3
        }
    ]
}

Comment: I want to make this query work :   db.nwt_envio_contacto.aggregate({$project:{"visualizacoes":true,"envio_id":true}},{$match:{"envio_id":ObjectId("54c5ed8101ec09c26c7b23c6"),"visualizacoes":{$elemMatch:{"index":1}}}}, {$group:{_id:null,total:{$sum:"visualizacoes.$.total"}}})

Comment: Basically i want to sum the total atribute of all visualizacoes objects that have the index equal to 1. Don't say that I have no visualizacoes with index equal to 1, because I only showed one document of my collection. I have many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This aggregation will sum all visualizacoes objects that have the index equal to 1:

```
db.nwt_envio_contacto.aggregate([
    {$match:{
        "envio_id":ObjectId("54c5ed8101ec09c26c7b23c6")
    }},
    {$unwind: "$visualizacoes"},
    {$match:{
        "visualizacoes.index":1
    }},
    {$group:{
        _id:null,
        total:{  
            $sum:"$visualizacoes.total"
        }
    }}
])
```

You can use the [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator to flatten the array and after filtering the entries where the index is 1, you are ready to sum.